# Trouble debugging ASP.NET site: loading debugger times out

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, visual-studio-debugging

Intermittently, my team's (overweight) VS2010 solution fails to load in the debugger. We get informed that "The web server did not respond in a timely manner".

Workarounds for when this happens:

- Build, then debug (but not hitting F5 before building)
- IIS Reset
- Killing other apps, or closing extra open tabs in my *other* browser (debugging in IE, browsing stuff/keeping Gmail open in Opera)

Is there a registry key we could set that would make the response timeout longer, or similar?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the hint of an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/787334/822637):

There are [registry keys](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/614606/debug-visualizer-for-datatable-cause-debugger-to-crash-function-evaluation-timed-out) that control timeouts for VS's debugger. As these are generally not documented, it's a matter of trial and error from here.

So far I've been toying with `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\(version number)\Debugger\ScriptDocsTimeout`