# Visual Studio 2015 Watch Evaluation Timed Out

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, registry, visual-studio-debugging

While debugging and stepping through code, I tried to add a method to the watch window which takes a long time to evaluate (probably 20-30 sec as it involves network connectivity). After about 15 seconds however, I get "evaluation timed out" error.

I found the following solution which involves changing the registry value `NormalEvalTimeout` under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\Debugger` to extend the timeout length:

[How to keep Visual Studio debugger visualizers from timing out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787334/how-to-keep-visual-studio-debugger-visualizers-from-timing-out)

However I don't seem to have that entry in my registry (or any other timeout related entries for that matter). I also looked in the WOW64 regedit. I tried to create the `NormalEvalTimeout` entry from scratch but that had no effect.

Any ideas where to find the registry entry or if there is another way to do this with VS 2015? Thanks for the help.

Edit: here is the list of registry entries I have (on Windows Server 2012 R2):
[image]

Comment: When you created it "from scratch" did you put it in `VisualStudio\14.0\Debugger` or `9.0`? You tagged your question`visual-studio-2015`, which has its configuration under `14.0`.

Comment: Sorry, it was 14.0, I fixed the question.

Comment: @amite, so this issue has been resolved, am I right? If so, would you please share your solution as the answer, and then mark it. So it could help other community members who meet the same issue as yours.

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT - unfortunately the issue itself wasn't resolved. I just made a mistake when writing the question and following Rene's comment, fixed that mistake. My registry has no `...VisualStudio\9.0\Debugger` path like I initially wrote by but a `...VisualStudio\14.0\Debugger` path. The issue still holds as described above.

Comment: @amite, Open VS, Tools -> Options->Debugging, uncheck "Enable property evaluation and other implicit function calls", how about the result? I also couldn't find it in my registry. Maybe it is related to the endless loop or some busy process. Without using tool-tip/watch data, maybe you could check it using other window like quickly watch window, and you could edit the QuickwatchTimeout value in registry if it still has this issue.

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT, I don't have QuickwatchTimeout value in registry either - can you point me to the registry path where it is? The reason for the long wait time in my case is that the call makes a network request, it's probably not a loop. Turning off auto-evaluation like you suggested does help a bit - several watches do get evaluated when I request them manually! However, this still doesn't always work and even when it does - I have to manually request evaluation for dozens of other inner params one by one, which is a pain.

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT -  I just scanned the registry, there is no QuickwatchTimeout value there.

Comment: @amite, I will check different Environments and update it here, but I have one windows 10 64 bit machine which installed the VS2015 Enterprise version with update3, it really has the QuickwatchTimeout in the path HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\Debugger.

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT - thanks for the update. I edited my post and added the list of registry entries I have.

Comment: @amite, I think it is the related to the windows Environment, I check the windows 10, it has QuickwatchTimeout like this link: https://1drv.ms/i/s!Auvjmr9ZOuhVhwl-tf7kwZzVwu67, but if I check the same windows 2012 R2 machine as yours, it really has no the timeout option.

Comment: @amite, I report this issue to the product team, and just post it as the provisional answer for this issue:)

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT - done. I hope we don't discover that the disappearance of registries keys is by design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As our previous discussions, we could make sure that it really has no the registry value NormalEvalTimeout under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\Debugger, and if you want to set the timeout value for other debugging windows, it also has the requirement for the Windows Environment. At least, we make sure that it doesn't have them in the windows server 2012 R2.

I help you report a feedback to the product team here for the two issues:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedbackdetail/view/3125884/visual-studio-2015-watch-evaluation-timed-out

If possible, you could vote and add your comments in that connect report. The product team experts would share us the updated information here:)