# Visual Studio watch time out

Tags: c#, list, linq

I am debugging a program in Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 Community, version 16.11.31.

I'd like to "export" some list values to my editor for easier understanding.

I tried to do this with `string.Join()` and Linq `Select(x => $"{x.StringValue1} {x.StringValue2}")` methods.

The problem is that the execution times out.

[image]

Is there a way to extend the allowed execution time or anyhow else get this data? The dataset is really not that big, only 21 entries.

I don't know what causes this, but it occurs to just sometimes.

I tried to convert it to list and to array, with no success. I tried to only select the string values and not use string interpolation, also selecting just one property times out.

I was looking at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42400972/visual-studio-2015-watch-evaluation-timed-out) but I don't have any similar setting in the registry.

I'd like to print out these 21 entries as string.

Comment: Do you have some code in the get accessor for the _TranslatedCategoryNames_ property?

Comment: What kind of collection is `_relations`? Is it backed by some kind of queryable data store, or is it truly just a `List<>`?

Comment: It is a `List<>` but I checked and one of its properties has a reference to some proprietary tanslation service that may be the reason for slow response.

The question remains: can I extend the timeout?