# How to increase visualizer timeout for Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio

This was answered for [previous versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787334/how-to-keep-visual-studio-debugger-visualizers-from-timing-out),

However in version 15 (VS2017), the same registries for increasing **NormalEvalTimeout** and **QuickwatchTimeout** are missing.

[image]

Comment: Having the same problem and failed to find the solution. Simply creating the registry key by hand does not seem help...

Answer (score 3):

For newer versions of Visual Studio, this setting was moved to settings file. You should look to modify the **LongEvalTimeout**, **NormalEvalTimeout** and/or **QuickwatchTimeout** properties in the following file

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\**YYYY**\**VERSION**\Common7\IDE\Profiles\**LANG**.vssettings

Where

- **YYYY** is the VS version (e.g. 2017 or 2019)
- **VERSION** Enterprise or Professional
- **LANG** is the programming language you want to change the setting for (e.g. CSharp, VB or VC)

Comment: Changing these values is not working for me in Visual Studio 2019. I'm using ANTLR4ParseTreeVisualizer. https://github.com/zspitz/ANTLR4ParseTreeVisualizer/

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was coming in Visual Studio 2017 and to fix that I tried this:

I enabled the following setting:

Debug > Options > "Use Managed Compatibility Mode"

[image]

Comment: This completely disables features like lambdas within QuickWatch, which is typically not an option...